# How to restrict one user from viewing others data by changing the record Id value in the route?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing as asp.net MVC application and I have two routes first is
http://localhost:60184/Owner/Edit/11 which belongs to user-1 and the second is http://localhost:60184/Owner/Edit/1 to user-2. I want both users to edit, delete, update only his/her own data and for that I have use [Authorize(Roles = "Owner")] but both owners can see each other data by only changing the id value in the route?
Any one please help how to solve this?

Comment: You have to do it on server side, get the Id from URL, check the current user has permission to edit it (by querying the user permission related table data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add OwnerId field to your database table that you want to edit and compare it with the current user ID.

```
public ActionResult Edit(SomeVmClass model)
{
      var entity = //fetch the entity from DB
      if(User.Identity.GetUserId() != entity.OwnerId)
            return HttpNotFound();
      // your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks I did the similar kind of solution.